# How to cache jclass?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

For performance issue, I had to cache a jclass, but NewGlobalRef only accepted a jobject as input, looks like jni doesn't allow user to cache a jclass? Will it work if I have to strongly cast jclass to jobject?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to cast. `jclass` is internally just a typedef for `jobject`.